# Why don't I have ability to edit posts on meta having editing priveleges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

I have 250 repz and rep on meta has been already updated long time ago, however "edit" link is disabled for me on the meta posts. As far I remember, priveleges rep level should be the same on meta and main.

Wait, [/review](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/review) there states that closevoting requires 500 repz... mess...

Comment: I don't know, and I am reproing this. But my guess is that the [special case](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/a/223/10011) for Ask Patents' privilege levels might not have carried through to meta. I say that mostly since the tooltip still says "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the privileges for AskPatents were adjusted back to their original values (following a large code change), the meta ones were not adjusted in the same way (they never were, originally).

This was most probably an oversight, which I have now corrected.